# Fusionauth-app docker without mysql superuser credentials

Tags: docker-compose, fusionauth

I would like to connect to a hosted remote mySQL DB (mariadb 10.1.39). I use   the available fusionauth docker images (app and search) from docker hub and the published docker compose file. The db hosting provider does not grant superuser credentials. The assigned user rights should be sufficient to maintain the tables of the schema. Unfortunately, using the docker container mysql superuser credentials seems to be mandatory.

I imported the DB dump of a local (dockerized) mariadb (10.1.40) to the remote db. Username and schema name are the same local and remote. I tried not to provide DATABASE_ROOT_USER with the docker-compose yaml, but this approach ends in maintenance mode.

Is there an approach to connect to a remote mysql db without superuser credentials?

Answer (score 0):

We will be enhancing our automated setup to better support external db service providers. See https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues/issues/95

Your current option is to create the schema manually. https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/installation-guide/fusionauth-app#advanced-installation

You may also try to use your user credentials in the superuser fields, it may work.